# Elmah - Catch an Error, but still log it and send email?

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net, elmah

First I found that you can catch it and log it inside a catch, but this doesn't send an email. 
Then I found out about using the `Error Signal` class. That worked, however what wasn't apparent from reading, is that it treats the error like normal, so when I signal the error it goes to the custom error page still, I don't want that to happen.

What I want to do is catch that error, log it, send the email, but stay on the page the error happened so I can provide special feedback. I do not want it go to the custom error page.

How can I accomplish this?

EDIT: This is what I have and it redirects me to the custom error page.

```
    Try
        smtpClient.Send(mailMessage)
    Catch smtpEx As SmtpException
        errorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(smtpEx)
    Catch ex As Exception
        errorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(ex)          
    End Try
```

Edit: Posting my web.config sections that involve Elmah (besides the connection string hah)
And there is nothing in my Global.asax file involving Elmah.

```
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="elmah">
        <section name="security" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.SecuritySectionHandler, Elmah" />
        <section name="errorLog" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorLogSectionHandler, Elmah" />
        <section name="errorMail" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorMailSectionHandler, Elmah" />
        <section name="errorFilter" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterSectionHandler, Elmah" />
    </sectionGroup>
</configSections> 
 <elmah>
<security allowRemoteAccess="1" />
<errorLog type="Elmah.SqlErrorLog, Elmah" connectionStringName="Elmah.Sql" applicationName="Web Main" />
<errorMail from="xxx" to="xxx" cc="xxx" subject="main website error" async="true" smtpPort="25" smtpServer="xxx" userName="xxx" password="xxx" />
<errorFilter>
  <test>
    <and>
      <equal binding="HttpStatusCode" value="404" type="Int32" />
      <regex binding="FilterSourceType.Name" pattern="mail" />
    </and>
  </test>
</errorFilter>
</elmah>
 <httpHandlers>
        <add verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="errors/admin/elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" />
    </httpHandlers>
    <httpModules>
        <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" />
        <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" />
        <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" />
    </httpModules>
 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
      <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
      <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <add name="Elmah" path="elmah/admin/elmah.axd" verb="POST,GET,HEAD" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" preCondition="integratedMode" />
    </handlers>
    <httpErrors>
            <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
      <remove statusCode="500" subStatusCode="-1" />
      <error statusCode="500" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/errors/error.asp" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
            <error statusCode="404" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/global/404.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
    </httpErrors>
  </system.webServer>
<location path="errors/admin/elmah.axd">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <deny users="?" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Comment: +1 because i didn't know Elmah before, it's for `ASP.Net` only(then Tag it)?

Comment: ok, it seems you aren't calling the Elmah method in the static way (Elmah.ErrorSignal....) it looks like you are assigning an object to Elmah.Error signal, maybe try accessing it in the static method Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(ex); (or the vb equivilant)

Comment: Did you ever come up with solution for this? About to ask a similar question. I want to send the elmah email when I catch an exception (in one place)

Answer (score 21):

The below should work (i do the exact same thing you are talking about)

```
try {
  // do something
} catch (Exception ex) {
  Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(ex); // logs and sends the error through elmah
  // write a message to the user
}
```

and if you want a nice framework for displaying the message you can check out [smokesignals](http://github.com/jonezy/smokesignals/) (disclaimer: it's my work)

Comment: This doesn't work as I said in my original post. When I use ErrorSignal to raise it, I still get re-directed to the custom error page

Comment: that's very strange because I do the exact same thing, and I have an ERror handler in my global.asax.cs and as soon as I trap the error it stop's bubbling up and never get's redirected, could you post some code?

Comment: You could explain about the error handler in global.asax? I don't have anything like that. All the elmah settings are in the web.config

Comment: in my global.asax i have " public void Application_Error(..) " which is where your exceptions end up if you don't catch and handle them in code, this is where I also redirect to an error page as well

Comment: I don't have anything like that and my uncaught errors get fine. Pretty sure because of my web.config, but I am not sure what I need to change then.

Comment: can you post your web.config?  This is really confusing as the whole point of "catching" errors is to prevent the behaviour that you are getting!

Comment: Edited my post to include any and all references of elmah in the web.config

Answer (score 1):

```
Try
'      do something
Catch ex As Exception
    ' logs and sends the error through elmah
    ' write a message to the user
Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(ex)
End Try
```

Also smokesignals goes to a 404

The question is tagged as a vb.net question, please have some respect

Comment: respect for what?  I write c# so it was quicker to post an example in that language?  Is it about the library? You should be able to use that in vb.net, sorry but your request for respect makes no sense.

Comment: @jonezy: why the downvote? This answer has the same content as yours. @Billy: I would upvote to correct this, but I have already hit my voting limit for the day.

Comment: the down vote is for demanding respect what no disrespect was given.

Comment: @jonezy: The voting system in this community is not about personal retribution; it is to show which answers provide the best results for a given question.

Comment: and that's your opinion, it's also to point out to people that making comments like "The question is tagged as a vb.net question, please have some respect" that those types of comments are unproductive and shouldn't/don't need to be made.

Comment: @jonezy: actually, that is not my opinion. That is why the system was set up: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation-gain I am not trying to get into a shouting match here; rather, I am trying to educate you and our new user (@Billy) about how the community works.

Comment: so down voting (what i perceived) to be a disrespectful statement is then a no go? Sorry but i think that down voting disrespectful statements follows in the same vein.  His answer was correct and complete and the comment about having respect wasn't needed at all.

Comment: again, not about personal retribution, it's about pointing out that the answer was enough and the smart ass comment went to far.

Comment: Fight Fight Fight Fight!!! => http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/41606_2346078629_3365458_n.jpg